# How to close the child view in my Android custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I had problem to implement the following scenario. My task is,

1. Show the content in Listview **(Implemented)**
2. When i click the listview need to show another layout with couple of buttons under clicked position. **(For your ref see the attached image, Implemented)**
3. Now the problem arise here, the child layout will close when the same item is clicked but my need is, i need to show the child layout if it is not show above, else i need to close it and show under the clicked layout.

So far i used the following code, to achieve this,

```
holder.layoutOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("Position", "" + position);
                if (holder.layoutTwo.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    holder.layoutTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    holder.layoutTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

As per the above code, i checked the visibility of layout two if its visible i closed it else i showed the layoutTwo. I know this code will suite only for same item click but i acheive the same for others, please share your thoughts.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Use the [Expandable ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ExpandableListView and to that bind an BaseExpandableListAdapter.

When you done that you could add a listener the every listitem in the list, called OnGroupExpandListener

Let say you have a class A that extends Activity. in this class you instanciate an ExpandableListView:

```
 ExpandableListView expListView.
```

Now you have an ExpandableListView-object.

To that you need to bind an adapter (BaseExpandableListAdpater) - create a class B that extends BaseExpandableListAdpater

To the expListView-object you can call the OnGroupExpandListener (that listens to clicks on the groupItems. I think this is what you want?)

```
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

        final int group_position = groupPosition; 
        int len = adapter.getGroupCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (i != groupPosition) {
                    expListView.collapseGroup(i);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```